# Bash - Recursively change ownership of only the directories which belong to a certain user/group

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory (we will call `/files`) with ~1300 subdirectories, each of which contains further subdirectories and files.

90% of the top level directories in `/files` belong to `apache:apache` and the rest belong to `root:root`. I need everything to belong to `apache:apache`.

I think if I do a recursive `chown` on the whole lot it will be quite extreme, so I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to recursively change ownership of just the `root:root` directories to `apache:apache`.

Bonus if `chmod` can be done on these directories in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive chown would have probably been done already, but you could use this instead:

```
find . -type d \( ! -user apache -o ! -group apache \) -print0 | xargs -0 chown apache:apache
```

To change directories that have the wrong permission:

```
find . -type d ! -perm 755 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755
```

Comment: The chown works a charm, but the chmod gives me `find: invalid predicate \`-mode\`` and `chmod: missing operand after '755'`

Comment: @BadHorsie Sorry, used the wrong flag, it shoud be `-perm`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using linux's find command is going to help there:

```
find /files -user root -group root -type d \
   -exec chmod something {} \; -exec chown apache.apache {} \;
```

for more details on WHY that works there is http://www.explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+%2Ffiles+-user+root+-group+root+-type+d+-exec+foo+\%3B